# How to change .navigationBarTitle alignment to trailing for iOS in SwiftUI (or, make it Right To Left)

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

I've modified the title font, color and background of `navigationBar` using `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes` and `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor`.

However I can't find any attribute to set the `navigationBarTitle` alignment to right (trailing).

Additionally, I've even tried `.navigationBarTitle(Text("Title").multilineTextAlignment(.leading))` modifier, but SwiftUI does not accept it. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: From multiple references like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880513/navigation-bar-titleview-alignment) on this topic, it's evident that the `Alignment` can't be changed for navigation bar's title.

Comment: @nayem It turns out it can be change. I answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change any `view` right-to-left by giving them below modifiers:

```
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
```

And it can be used for the navigation bar as well:

```
NavigationView {

  VStack {

//Your views ...

    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
  }

}
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
```