# Change navigation title position from left to right

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to move a navigation title to right side instead of left, any idea on how to implement that?

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Color.init("midnight blue")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)

            .navigationBarTitle("המרות מטבע")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    print("button pressed")

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change .navigationBarTitle alignment to trailing for iOS in SwiftUI (or, make it Right To Left)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391821/how-to-change-navigationbartitle-alignment-to-trailing-for-ios-in-swiftui-or)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for. But consider this is applied by iOS automatically dependend on your language settings.

```
NavigationView {
               Color.init("midnight blue")
                   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)

                   .navigationBarTitle("המרות מטבע")
                   .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                       Button(action: {
                           print("button pressed")

                       }) {
                           Image(systemName: "plus")
                               .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                   })
         }.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use navigationBarItem where in you can customise your text.
for me this code is working :

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Title on Right"))
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
```

[check result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGTwU.png)